# Prevent Postback using JavaScript

Tags: jquery, postback

I have the following code.  When the user hits [ENTER] (keycode = 13), the form is being resubmitted.  I'd like to prevent a postback in this condition.  When I set the keycode equal to 0, it does nothing.  The page postback is still occuring.  How can I prevent the post postback?

```
    jQuery(this.Elements.TxtClientId).keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            e.keyCode = 0;
            alert("keycode: " + e.keyCode);
            thisTemp._internalClientId = jQuery(thisTemp.Elements.TxtClientId).val();
            jQuery(thisTemp.Elements.DDLClientName).val(jQuery(thisTemp.Elements.TxtClientId).val());
            thisTemp.UpdateTestDropdown();             
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
 if(e.keyCode === 13){
       e.preventDefault();
       // remainder of your code
   }
```

per the question:
[Prevent a button to submit on enter key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075486/prevent-a-button-to-submit-on-enter-key)

Comment: What is the difference between 2 vs. 3 "=" signs?

Comment: Checks for equality with / without type coercion, respectively.
See this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript
(In your case, either should work)

Answer (score 1):

You need to prevent the default handler of the event. You are using jQuery so you can use the built in [preventDefault in jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

Answer (score 0):

i think you want preventDefault()!

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

try putting this instead of setting it to 0

```
e.preventDefault();
```